# Getting highest score values from firebase database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my website there are some films that i get from firebase. The scores of the movies are between 0 and 100. I already got all the movies in my website. I also want to display them in descending order.(for ex. top 5 rated movies) How can i achieve this? Thanks for your answers.

```js
           const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
           const db = getDatabase(app);
           const auth = getAuth(app);
           const firebaseRef= ref(getDatabase());
    
    
      var body = document.getElementById('movies');
      var body2 = document.getElementById('series');
    
    
    function AddItemsToTable(name, score, img, id) {
        var movies = `<div class="content"><a href="movieDetail.html?movieId=${id}"><img src="${img}" ></a><p><a href="movieDetail.html?movieId=${id}">${name}</a></p> <p> <i class="fa fa-star checked" id="star${id}"></i>&nbsp;<a class="scoretxt">${score}%</a> </p> </div>`;
        body.innerHTML+=movies;
    
    }
    function AddItemsToTable2(name, score, img, id) {
        var series = `<div class="content"><a href="seriesDetail.html?seriesId=${id}"><img src="${img}" ></a><p><a href="seriesDetail.html?seriesId=${id}">${name}</a></p> <p> <i class="fa fa-star checked" id="star2${id}"></i>&nbsp;<a class="scoretxt">${score}%</a> </p> </div>`;
        body2.innerHTML += series;
    
    }
    
    
    //*******************************I got the movies************************************************
            function AddAllItemsToTable(TheMovies){
              var counter=0;
                TheMovies.forEach(element => {
                  if (counter===6) {
                    return;
                  }
                    AddItemsToTable(element.movieName, element.movieScore, element.movieImage, element.movieId);
                 
                    counter++;
            });
          }
          //************************I got tv series*********************************************
          function AddAllItemsToTable2(TheSeries){
              var counter=0;
    
          TheSeries.forEach(element => {
            if (counter===6) {
              return;
            }
              AddItemsToTable2(element.seriesName, element.seriesScore, element.seriesImage, element.seriesId);
              counter++;
    
      });
    
        }
        function AddAllItemsToTable3(TheMovies){
          var counter=0;
            TheMovies.forEach(element => {
              if (counter===6) {
                return;
              }
                AddItemsToTable3(element.movieName, element.movieScore, element.movieImage, element.movieId);
               
                counter++;
        });
    
      }
    
            function getAllDataOnce(){
                const dbRef=ref(db);
                get(child(dbRef,"Movies"))
                        .then((snapshot)=>{
                            var movies=[];
                    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                        movies.push(childSnapshot.val())
                    });
                    AddAllItemsToTable(movies);
                });
            }
            function getAllDataOnce2(){
                const dbRef=ref(db);
                get(child(dbRef,"Series"))
                        .then((snapshot)=>{
                            var series=[];
                    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                        series.push(childSnapshot.val())
                    });
                    AddAllItemsToTable2(series);
    
                });
            }
    
    
                window.onload = (event) => {
                    getAllDataOnce();
                    getAllDataOnce2();
    };
```

```html
      <div class="grid-container">

          <header class="header">

              <div class="solheader">
                <a href="main.html" style="logo" class="big"> <img src="img/sonlogo3.png" alt="logo"></a>
                <a href="main.html" style="logo"  class="small"> <img src="img/logosmall.png" alt="logo" style="width:60px;height:48px;margin:5px;"></a>


              </div>
              <div class="ortaheader">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Movies or TV series.." class="searchbox"><i class="fa fa-search arama"></i>  </input>
                <ul>
                <li class="categories"><a href="#">Categories&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-caret-down" style="font-size:16px;"> </i></a>
                 <ul class="dropdown">
                      <li><a href="series.html">TV Series</a></li>
                      <li><a href="movies.html">Movies</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                  </ul>
              </div>

              <div class="menu sagheader">

                <ul>
                  <li>
                  <button class="ikon dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="far fa-user"></i>  </button>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                   <li class="accountname"><b><script>document.write(document.cookie.substring(5))</script></b></li>
                   <li class="login"><a href="login.html" style="color:red;"><i class="fa fa-sign-in-alt" style="color:red;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Login</a> </li>
                   <li class="signup"><a href="signup.html" style="color:red;"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" style="color:red;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Sign up</a> </li>
                   <li class="logout"><a onclick="deletecookie()" style="cursor:pointer;"><i class="fas fa-door-open" style="color:red;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
          </header>

          <div class="body" id="body">

              <div class="baslik">Movies</div>
              <div class="baslik2"><a href="movies.html">See all</a></div>
              <div id="movies">
              </div>

                <div class="baslik">Series</div>
                <div class="baslik2"><a href="series.html">See all</a></div>
              <div id="series">
              </div>

              <div class="baslik">Top Rated Movies</div>
              <div class="baslik2"><a href="#">See all</a></div>
              <div id="toprated">
              </div>



</div>
          <div class="footer">
              <div class="">
                  <img src="img/sonlogo3.png" alt="logo">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Terms and Policies</a></li>

                  </ul><br><br>
                  <ul>
                    <li>© 2021 Cinemeter</li>
                    <li class="destroy">|</li>

                    <li>All rights reserved.</li>
                  </ul>
              </div>


          </div>
        </div>
```

**Firebase Database**
[image]

**This is my website**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Firebase can order results, the results are always ascending. If you want to show them in descending order, you'll have to reverse them in your application code.

Something like this:

```
const query = query(child(dbRef,"Movies"), orderByChild("movieScore"));
get(query).then((snapshot)=>{
    var movies=[];
    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        movies.push(childSnapshot.val())
    });
    movies.reverse
});
```

If you want to get the top scores, you can use `limitToLast` in the query too:

```
const query = query(child(dbRef,"Movies"), orderByChild("movieScore"), limitToLast(5));
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [ordering and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) and [limiting the number of results](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#limit_the_number_of_results).

A few notes on your data structure:

- Using sequential numeric keys for you nodes is an anti-pattern in Firebase, and it is typically better to [use push keys](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data). Also see [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).
- You're storing the score as a string, which is bound to lead to problems as strings are sorted lexicographically. I recommend converting your data to store the scores as numbers (so without `"` quotes around them).

Comment: I did it. now i am gettin Uncaught (in promise) Error: Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "movieScore", for path "/Movies", to the rules
    at error

Comment: As the message says, you'll need to add that index in the indicated place. See the documentation on [adding indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) and previous [questions on this error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+Index+not+defined%2C+add+%22.indexOn%22+for+path+to+the+rules). ---